# how to get day difference in postgres

Tags: postgresql, days

I want to find out how many days are left until "End_date" is reached in postgres. What will be equivalent for following in postgres?

```
Days_Left = Column in table - Today's date 

GREATEST(INT4(CEIL(("NUMERIC"(DATE_PART('EPOCH'::"VARCHAR", (T1.End_date - "TIMESTAMP"(DATE('now'::"VARCHAR"))))) / '86400'::"NUMERIC"))), 0) AS DAYS_LEFT
```

--Thanks I tried your suggestion but did not get expected result.

Expected Result -- if use GREATEST(INT4(CEIL(("NUMERIC"(DATE_PART('EPOCH'::"VARCHAR", (CA.END_DATE - "TIMESTAMP"(DATE('now'::"VARCHAR"))))) / '86400'::"NUMERIC"))), 0)

```
End_date               Days_left
2014-11-01 03:59:00    47
2016-01-01 04:59:59    473
2017-01-01 06:59:59    839
2014-12-31 22:59:00    107
```

Result -  date(end_date) - date(current_date)

```
End_date                Days_Left
2014-11-01 03:59:00     46
2016-01-01 04:59:59     472
2017-01-01 06:59:59     838
2014-12-31 22:59:00     106
```

Result -  if use (end_date - current_date)

```
End_date                Days_Left
2014-11-01 03:59:00     46 days 03:59
2016-01-01 04:59:59     472 days 04:59:59
2017-01-01 06:59:59     838 days 06:59:59
2014-12-31 22:59:00     106 days 22:59
```

Thanks
Sandy

Comment: `TIMESTAMP"(DATE('now'::"VARCHAR"))` makes no sense whatsoever. This can be replaced with a simple `current_date`

Answer (score 1):

If `column_in_table` is defined as a `DATE` you can use this:

```
select column_in_table - current_date as days_left
from the_table
```

**Edit**

As `end_date` is a timestamp the above expression will return an `interval` not an integer.

If you don't care about the hours and minutes left, casting the `timestamp` to a `date` should work:

```
select end_date::date - current_date as days_left
from the_table
```

Comment: Thanks .I have tried this option but did not get expected result. Please see my first post for details.

Comment: Apparently your `end_date` is defined as a `timestamp` column. If you don't care about the minutes and hours casting the column to a `date` before doing the subtraction should work.

Comment: yes , end_date column is Timestamp and Days_Left Column is Integer , I tried date() but there is a difference of 1 day. Please see my first post with example.